# Vectorised way to calculate mean of left and right neighbours in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
x = c(1820.0, 2235.0, 2534.0, 2580.0, 2322.0, 2317.0, 2331.0, 2345.0, 
      2305.0, 2265.0, 2277.0, 2289.0, 2338.0, 2387.0, 2152.0, 2256.0, 
      2360.0, 2590.0, 2529.0, 2468.0, 2776.0, 2909.0, 3017.0, 3081.0,
      3118.5, 3156.0, 3338.0, 3211.5)
```

I want to calculate the mean of left and right neighbors of each element except edges. For example, the result should be like this :  `mean(1820,2534), mean(2235,2580), mean(2534,2322) ...`

I am able to do this using loops but that is very slow. I need a vectorized solution.

My code using a for loop:

```
neighbour_m = function(x) {
  newx = c(x[length(x)], x, x[1])
  for (i in 2:(length(newx) - 1)){
    m = mean(c(newx[i-1], newx[i+1]))
  }
}
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18436574/680068

Answer (score 20):

In base R you can use filter :

```
stats::filter(x, c(1/2, 0, 1/2), sides = 2)
```

Then remove `NA` using `na.omit`.

Comment: Very neat. I like the use of `stats::filter`. +1

Comment: @Clemsang, can we use the filter function to calculate sd just like mean

Comment: @gi.rajan You can use if for anything that is based on a sum. That includes the variance / standard deviation.

Answer (score 12):

Another base R option using `rowMeans` and `cbind`

```
rowMeans(cbind(x[1:(length(x) - 2)], x[3:(length(x))]))
# [1] 2177.00 2407.50 2428.00 2448.50 2326.50 2331.00 2318.00 2305.00 2291.00
#[10] 2277.00 2307.50 2338.00 2245.00 2321.50 2256.00 2423.00 2444.50 2529.00
#[19] 2652.50 2688.50 2896.50 2995.00 3067.75 3118.50 3228.25 3183.75
```

Comment: My benchmark using package `microbenchmark` says this answer is the fastest.

Answer (score 8):

Using `lag`/`lead` from dplyr:

```
library("dplyr")
na.omit(rowMeans(data.frame(lag(x, 1), lead(x, 1))))
#  [1] 2177 2408 2428 2448 2326 2331 2318 2305 2291 2277 2308 2338 2245 2322 2256
# [16] 2423 2444 2529 2652 2688 2896 2995 3068 3118 3228 3184
# attr(,"na.action")
# [1]  1 28
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "omit"
```

Comment: Wonder why you have no decimals?

Comment: `options("digits")` was set to 4

Answer (score 6):

There should be some simpler solution to this but here is one way using `zoo::rollapply`. We create a sequence of odd and even indices for the length of the vector, subset `x` for rolling 2 points and take `mean` of them.

```
a1 <- zoo::rollapply(seq(2, length(x), by = 2), 2, function(i) mean(x[i]))
a2 <- zoo::rollapply(seq(1, length(x), by = 2), 2, function(i) mean(x[i]))
c(rbind(a1, a2))

#[1] 2407.50 2177.00 2448.50 2428.00 2331.00 2326.50 2305.00 2318.00 2277.00 
#    2291.00 2338.00 2307.50 2321.50 2245.00 2423.00 2256.00 2529.00 2444.50 
#    2688.50 2652.50 2995.00 2896.50 3118.50 3067.75 3183.75 3228.25
```

Answer (score 6):

Using *head*, *tail*, then *rowMeans*:

```
rowMeans(cbind(head(x, -2), tail(x, -2)))
#  [1] 2177.00 2407.50 2428.00 2448.50 2326.50 2331.00 2318.00 2305.00
#  [9] 2291.00 2277.00 2307.50 2338.00 2245.00 2321.50 2256.00 2423.00
# [17] 2444.50 2529.00 2652.50 2688.50 2896.50 2995.00 3067.75 3118.50
# [25] 3228.25 3183.75
```

Similarly:

```
colMeans(rbind(head(x, -2), tail(x, -2)))
```

Answer (score 6):

**1) rollapply** This says to pass the indicated offsets (-1 = prior value, +1 = next value) to the function, `mean`, and run it as a rolling application of `mean`.  This does require a package but on the other hand it is concise and does not require any index manipulations.  It is also allows flexible handling of the edges in that if we want to return a vector the same length as the input we can add the argument `fill = NA` or `partial = TRUE` to fill with NA values or to perform partial computations at the edges.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(x, list(c(-1, 1)), mean)
```

giving:

```
 [1] 2177.00 2407.50 2428.00 2448.50 2326.50 2331.00 2318.00 2305.00 2291.00
[10] 2277.00 2307.50 2338.00 2245.00 2321.50 2256.00 2423.00 2444.50 2529.00
[19] 2652.50 2688.50 2896.50 2995.00 3067.75 3118.50 3228.25 3183.75
```

**2) rollsum**  Another approach is to use rollsum and then subtract out the current value and divide by 2.  Drop the `na.omit` if you want an output the same length as `x` with NAs on the end.

```
library(zoo)
na.omit(rollsum(x / 2, 3, fill = NA) - x / 2)
```

giving:

```
 [1] 2177.00 2407.50 2428.00 2448.50 2326.50 2331.00 2318.00 2305.00 2291.00
[10] 2277.00 2307.50 2338.00 2245.00 2321.50 2256.00 2423.00 2444.50 2529.00
[19] 2652.50 2688.50 2896.50 2995.00 3067.75 3118.50 3228.25 3183.75
attr(,"na.action")
[1]  1 28
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

**3) Matrix operator**  This operation is linear so it can be represented by a matrix.  In particular, we can multiply `x` by a matrix having a 0.5 on the super and sub-diagonals and zeros elsewhere.

```
d <- diag(length(x))
y <- ((abs(row(d) - col(d)) == 1) / 2) %*% x
```

This gives partial evaluation at the end points so if you don't want that then NA them out `y[c(1, length(y))] <- NA` or drop the endpoints `y <- y[-c(1, length(y))]` .